# How do i use SimpleQueryString function of elasticsearch?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to write a django app and use elasticsearch in it with elasticsearch-dsl library of python. I don't want to create all switch-case statements and then pass search queries and filters accordingly.

I want a function that does the parsing stuff by itself.
For e.g. If i pass "some text url:github.com tags:es,es-dsl,django",
the function should output corresponding query.

I searched for it in elasticsearch-dsl documentation and found a function that does the parsing.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=simplequerystring&type=
However, I dont know how to use it.
I tried `s = Search(using=client).query.SimpleQueryString("1st|ldnkjsdb")`, but it is showing me parsing error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: As of now, your question is unclear. Please clarify a little bit more what you mean - You want to pass in a query string, and receive what in return? The results of the query? A query object?

Comment: Have you tried to write any code yourself? If you have, please edit your post to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just plug the `SimpleQueryString` in the `Search` object, instead of a dictionary send the elements as parameters of the object.

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import SimpleQueryString

client = Elasticsearch()
_search = Search(using=client, index='INDEX_NAME')

_search = _search.filter( SimpleQueryString(
     query = "this + (that | thus) -those", 
     fields= ["field_to_search"],
     default_operator= "and"
))
```

A lot of `elasticsearch_dsl` simply change the dictionary representation to classes of functions that makes the code look pythonic, and avoid the use of hard-to-read elasticsearch JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are asking about the usage of elasticsearch-dsl with query string like you are making a request with json data to the elasticsearch api. If that's the case, this is how you are going to use elasticsearch-dsl:

assume you have the query in *query* variable like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
        }
    }
}
```

and now do this:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    host=settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_IP, # Put your ES host IP
    port=settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_PORT, # Put yor ES host port
)
index = settings.MY_INDEX # Put your index name here
result = es.search(index=index, body=query)
```